# How to add a property to a map?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a domain class:

```
class Person {
    String name
    Boolean likesGrails
    Boolean isSmart
}
```

and want to pre process the data (create a new property `friend`) before passing it to a view (which will use `friend` to decide stuff):

```
def people = Person.list()
people.each {
    it.friend = likesGrails && isSmart
}
```

How do i add this `friend` property? The code above doesn't work (it complains that `it.friend` doesn't exist).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should just be able to add:

```
static transients = [ 'friend' ]
public boolean isFriend() {
  likesGrails && isSmart
}
```

To your domain class, then access `person.friend` in your view

Comment: is it possible to add a property to a groovy map (say if `people` didn't come from hibernate but was just defined as `def people = [....])?

Comment: Yeah, you should just be able to add it like in your question :-)

Comment: @zoran119 eg: `[[a:1,b:2],[a:3,b:4]].collect { it.c = it.a + it.b ; it }`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a transient if you don't want it to be stored in your database.

```
class Person {
       String name
       Boolean likesGrails
       Boolean isSmart

       Boolean friend
       static transients = [ 'friend' ]
}
```

but you can't add random properties on the fly to domain classes.